# Solving for points such that the tangent is parallel to the x-axis on a lemniscate.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, implicit-differentiation

I am asked to find ${y}'$ of $(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2} = a^{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})$ with  $y(x)$ and $a$ as a positive constant, which is given in the solutions as:

$
{y}'(x) = \frac{(a^{2}-2(x^{2}+y^{2}))x}{(2(x^{2}+y^{2})+a^{2})y}
$

Side question: Although I find this mechanically, I don't fully understand how to interpret the derivative of something that isn't a function. How does this work?

Then the question asks for the points on the original graph where the tangent is parallel to the x-axis. The solutions give $x = \pm\frac{1}{4}a\sqrt{6}$ and $y = \pm\frac{1}{4}a\sqrt{2}$, which I haven't been able to find (after setting the above derivative to $0$). Can anyone help me with this question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: On the side question, $y$ *is* a function of $x$, by the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) - see the article for details and caveats, but just because you don't have $y$ given explicitly by a formula that depends only on $x$, does not mean that it is not a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your derivative is correct, it needs to be 0 so first you get $a^2/2 = x^2 + y^2$.  Then use that to replace $x^2 + y^2$ in the curve equation which gives $a^2/4 = x^2 - y^2$.  Then add those two equations together and you can get x in terms of $a$ and you are virtually home free.

Comment: Nice answer. However, you may wish to mention that $x = 0$ is not a valid choice for the derivative to be $0$ due to the original equation then becoming $y^4 = -a^2y^2$, which requires $y = 0$, so $y'\left(x\right)$ would be then an indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$.